# Snowflake result renames column

Tags: sql

The resultscan on last query renames the common column

```
select 'a' as col,'b' as col;
```

gives resultset columns as `col,col`

```
select * from table(result_scan(last_query_id(-1)))
```

gives resultset  column as `col,col_1`

Answer (score 1):

Query:

```
select 'a' as col,'b' as col;
```

gives:

[image]

Checking metadata:

```
DESC RESULT LAST_QUERY_ID();
```

gives:

[image]

So yes, the numbering is different (`COL_2` vs `COL_1`) depending on which method is used to access metadata and it should be reported to Snowflake support.